# Private beta A51 link broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, private-beta, broken-link

Apparently either markdown isn't supported on the [private beta log-in page](http://digitalfabrication.stackexchange.com/users/login?returnurl=%2f) or someone doesn't know how to use it.

[image]

Comment: That's not how you format a link in Markdown

Comment: The text should be swapped (the text in the brackets and parentheses)

Comment: Now people expect programmers to know how to *use* the things they implement!? What is the world coming to!?

Comment: Worth to mention that it's OK in the mobile theme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Templating strikes again. Fixed in build 2013.8.27.974

Comment: And meta build? ;)

Comment: 1383, since you insist ;)

Comment: Oh, too bad it's not 1337!

Comment: ... still something to look forward to in the sites build numbers