# Private beta markdown shows ** instead of bold

Tags: bug, markdown, private-beta

Private beta [login page](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/users/login?ssrc=beta&returnurl=%2F) shows `**private beta**` instead of making the text bold. Based on this question the [markdown is supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194723/196120) on the login page (however 4 years ago it was shown in italics).

[image: Double asterisk instead of bold]